# compare the value with the key in a dictionary

Tags: python

```
class VariableRateLoan(Loan):
    def __init__(self, term, rateDict, face):
        super(VariableRateLoan, self).__init__(term, rateDict, face)
        self._term = float(term)
        self._face = float(face)
      
        if type(rateDict) is not dict:
            print('Please enter the rate as a dict')
        else:
            self._rateDict = rateDict

    def getRate(self, T):
        keyList = list(self._rateDict.keys())
        if T > self._term:
            print('Term entered cannot exceed the total terms of this loan!')
        for i, v in enumerate(keyList):
            if keyList[i] <= T < keyList[i+1]:
                return self._rateDict[keyList[i]]
            else:
                return self._rateDict[max(self._rateDict.keys())]
```

Below is my test program

```
def main():
    rate_dict = {0: 0.03, 5: 0.05, 11: 0.07}
    loan1 = VariableRateLoan(120, rate_dict, 100000)
    print(loan1.getRate(7))
```

So basically, if I enter T=7 for getRate, I should get a rate at T=5, which is 0.05, but now it returns 0.07 for me. But if I enter anything below 5, it correctly gave me a 0.03 which starts from T=0. I was unsure what was wrong with my code.

keyList[i] <= T < keyList[i+1] (Here is the logic I try to achieve, if T entering is in a range between the two keys, it will return the value by using the lower key)

One thing to notice: I don't really sort the key because every dictionary passing in starts from 0, ends at a later term.

Comment: Can you clarify if you want the *closest* key, or do you want to select the *next largest* key?

Comment: You do get 0.05 without the else statement on your getRate right? After checking 0 on the first condition within the loop, and fails, it checks 5, passes the condition and return the expected value ... The current loop will always only check the first element, and based on it value, run what's on the if statement or the else

Comment: the for loop in `get_Rate()` will never actually loop, because you have if-return-else-return which must return.

Comment: @ddejohnI want the key smaller than the value I entered. for example: {0: 0.03, 5: 0.05, 11: 0.07}, if I pass getRate(7), 7 is the number between 5 and 11, so I expect to get 0.05 (the key is 5), if I pass getRate(3), I expect to get 0.03, because 3 is the number between 0 and 5. But if I passgetRate(13), I expect to get 0.07, because 13 is larger than 11 or any other keys, but still smaller than the term of 120.

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May not be the most elegant one, but should be simple to read at

```
def getRate(self, T):
    if T > self._term:
        print("Term entered cannot exceed the total terms of this loan!")
    
    required_key = max(term for term in self._rateDict if term <= T)
    return self._rateDict[required_key]
```

Comment: I'd suggest removing the square brackets, as `max()` will accept a generator expression. No need to create an intermediary list. You can also iterate directly over keys, so you could shorten your expression to `return self._rateDict[max(k for k in self._rateDict if k <= T)]`

Comment: @ddejohn Thanks for the advice. But for the second one, rateDict needs not to be sorted as it look for the max value.

Comment: Correct. My apologies.